# Order of assemblies returned by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wondering what's the rule that determines the order in which data is returned by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`? I have two similar executables but when I run the method, the order I got are drastically different -- any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is an implementation detail and may change in the future or for any number of other reasons. There is really no good reason why you should be relying on this

Comment: Have you tried sorting by name? Would that help?

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks for the answer! Yes, sorting by name does help me get a deterministic order. I guess my question is really about what determines the output of the `GetAssemblies()` call. I ran my program again and it seems one executable has System.Cryptography.Csp in the output and the other does not.